# What happens to thread started in the class instance when all references to the instance are destroyed (Python)?

Tags: python, multithreading

Question is in the title.

Code example:

```
class A:
    def start_thread(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=something)
        t1.start()

a = A()
a.start_thread()
a = A()
```

So, what happens to the thread, which we started?

Comment: You never actually started the thread. You created it, then it gets immediately discarded. You have to call the `Thread` object's `start` method to actually cause `something` to run.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I will fix the code above. Question still stands though - it was typo in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `threading` module itself keeps a reference to each active `Thread` object, so a running thread will continue to run even if the reference goes away.

Comment: Bad summary on my part. `threading._dangling` is an instance of `WeakSet`, to which each thread adds itself upon creation, but it appears that each thread also adds itself to `threading._active` (an ordinary `dict`) when its `start` method is called. I'm not entirely sure what `_dangling` is for; it seems to have something to do with cleaning up state after a fork.

Comment: I'll remove the word `weak` from the answer, as the weak references aren't really relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Threads are kept in a separate registry in the Python runtime, and you can "see" them by calling `threading.enumerate` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.enumerate)  - 
this is no different then not keeping a reference to a thread started in any other way.